# Reflection and dynamic method resolution

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

It is safe to assume that when calling a method via reflection (or using dynamic) the most specific one is selected, as in ordinary code?

Let's consider this code:

```
public class Animal {}
public class Dog : Animal {}

public class MyClass
{
    public void SayHello(Dog animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello dog!");
    }

    public void SayHello(Animal animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello animal!");
    }
}
```

When calling it with:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

// Classic invocation
myClass.SayHello(new Dog());

// Reflection
var method = myClass.GetType().GetMethod("SayHello", new[] { typeof(Dog) });
method.Invoke(myClass, new object[] { new Dog() });

// dynamic
((dynamic)myClass).SayHello((dynamic)new Dog());
```

When calling `SayHello` is the correct method invoked using the classic method resolution? In other words the output will be always `"Hello dog!"`?

From a quick test the answer seems to be **yes**, but I cannot find any specific documentation on MSDN.

Comment: I think the best way to know is to just try it yourself, you already have the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `dynamic` always resolves the parameter (in this case `new Dog()`) to the most specific type possible.